# Prove that if $x > 0$ then $1/x > 0$ using axioms of real numbers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Prove that if $x > 0$ then $1/x > 0$ using axioms of real numbers

This is how I attempted to solve this problem. However, I am not entirely sure whether the contradiction I got is enough to finish the proof, as none of the axioms explicitly states that $1>0$:

(1) Assume that $1/x < 0$. 
 (2) Multiply both sides of the inequality by $x > 0$ 
(3) $1<0$ - Contradiction, therefore the assumption was false.

Comment: You can show $1>0$ since $1=1^{2}>0,$ since all squares should be positive.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet
But none of the axioms states that $x^2 > 0$

Comment: But that is a trivial proof, right... If you have the axiom that $p>0$ and $b>c$ implies $pb>pc$ (as it appears in your reasoning above), then if $a<0$, you have $(-a)a<(-a)0$, i.e. $-a^2 <0$ and $a^2>0$. If $a>0$, it follows immediately.

Comment: Proposition 1.18(e)

https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf

Comment: Your reasoning looks basically OK (except that you should really assume $1/x\le0$ rather than $1/x\lt0$). What's lacking is *explicit* reference to the axioms that justify the steps.

Answer (score 1):

$$1>0$$

therefore

$$x\cdot\frac1x>0$$

Because $x>0$, $\frac1x>0$, via [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach) on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The axiom on the ordering says that if $x> 0$ and $\frac{1}{x} > 0$, then $x\cdot \frac{1}{x} > 0$, right?

Comment: I read it using negation, if $xy<0$ then $x<0$ or $y<0$. Because we don't have that, $1/x>0$.

Comment: How do you show $1 > 0$? This does not seem to be an explicit axiom.

Comment: It's negation contradicts Peano 8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Historical_second-order_formulation

Comment: @JMP What is that we don't have? $xy<0$?

Comment: It needs $x>0, xy>0 \implies y>0$. I'm not sure that that can be inferred from the WP article, so I tried the negation aspect - if $x<0$ xor $y<0$ then $xy\le0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument seems fine, up to the gap you mention: Why is $1 > 0$? To avoid confusion about the axioms, I will use the definition of an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Total_order) from Wikipedia, which has the two axioms:

1. $a < b \implies a+c < b+c$ for any $c$
2. If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then $ab > 0$.

Let's start with the following claim:
$$a < 0 \iff -a > 0.$$
*Proof*: The implication "$\implies$"can be seen by adding $c = -a$ to the inequality and using axiom 1. The converse can be seen by adding $a$ and axiom 1.

From this we can deduce: For any $a \neq 0$ we have
$$a^2 > 0.$$
*Proof*: If $a > 0$ this follows directly from axiom 2. If $a < 0$, we have $-a > 0$, so applying axiom 2 to $-a$ gives
$$0 < (-a)(-a) = a^2$$

In particular we deduce $1 = 1^2 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no explicit answer here, here's one method:

"Suppose $a \in \mathbb{F} ^{+}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Since $a \neq 0$, we have that $1/a \in \mathbb{F}$ exists by the multiplicative inverse axiom of fields. Note it should be obvious that $1/a \neq 0$ (why?).

Hence, using the property $$x\in \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\} \; \; \text{ implies } \; \; x^{2}>0,$$(like in the comments) we get $$(1/a)^{2}>0.$$It follows that $$a \cdot (1/a)^{2} > a \cdot 0,$$or equivalently, $1/a>0$. (Note the $1/a<0$ case is similar).

QED."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is to show that $1\gt 0$.

We know that either $1\gt 0$ or $-1\gt 0$ by the trichotomy axioms for ordering. Note that $1\ne 0$ otherwise we could easily show that all numbers are equal to $0$.

If $-1\gt 0$ then, since $-1$ and $x$ are both positive, we get that $-x\gt 0$ by the multiplicative closure axiom for positive numbers.

We can invoke trichotomy once again to point out that either $x$ or $-x$ are positive. Since $-x\gt 0$, $x$ is not positive, giving us a contradiction.

Therefore, $1\gt 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work in any ordered field $F$, so there exists a subset $P$ with the following properties:

1. $F$ is the disjoint union of $P$, $\{0\}$ and $-P=\{-a:a\in P\}$;
2. if $a,b\in P$, then $a+b\in P$;
3. if $a,b\in P$, then $ab\in P$.

Given such a subset $P$ we can define $a<b$ for $b-a\in P$ and prove this is an order relation compatible with the field operations. Conversely, given such an order relation, $P=\{a\in F:0<a\}$ satisfies the properties above and $a<b$ if and only if $b-a\in P$.

**Fact 1.** *If $a\in F$, $a\ne0$, then $a^2\in P$*
*Proof.* If $a\in P$, then $a^2\in P$ by property 3. If $a\in -P$, then $-a\in P$ and $a^2=(-a)^2\in P$.

**Fact 2.** $1=1^2\in P$

**Fact 3.** *If $a\in P$, then $1/a\in P$.*
*Proof.* Suppose, to the contrary, that $1/a\notin P$. Then $-1/a\in P$ and
$$
-1=-\frac{1}{a}a\in P
$$
which contradicts $1\in P$.